# Refactoring this RSpec bit of code to new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

How would you go with refactoring this piece of test-code using the 3.0 RSpec 'expect' syntax?

```
it "should destroy the micropost" do
  lambda do
    delete :destroy, :id => @micropost
    flash[:success].should =~ /deleted/i
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end.should change(Micropost, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
it "destroys the micropost" do
  expect {
    delete :destroy, :id => @micropost
    expect(flash[:success]).to match /deleted/i
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
  }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(-1)
end
```

sources: [`redirect_to`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher), [`match` and `change`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations)

Comment: i think `lambda` in `expect` is excess, you can use `expext { something }.to` instead.

Comment: @Monk_Code agreed - fixed this